# Unexpected token (14:13)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a simple web page with images using react, but on run npm start it keeps on complaining   *Unexpected token (14:13)*

**React codes:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function CardItem(props) {
return (
  <>
    <li className='cards__item'>
      <Link className='cards__item__link' to={props.path}>
        <figure className='cards__item__pic-wrap' data-category={props.label}>
          <img
            className='cards__item__img'
            alt='Travel Image'
            src={props.src}
          />
        </figure>
        <div className='cards__item__info'>
          <h5 className='cards__item__text'>{props.text}</h5>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </li>
  </>
);
}

export default CardItem;
```

**Error message.**
Unexpected token on **data-category ={props.label}**

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you maybe copy pasted some code online? If so, check for windows/unix line endings, hidden chars and that kinda stuff.

Comment: @0stone0 thank for advice you can check my codes now

Comment: And of course if you remove `data-category` error disappears correct?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito when I remove the data-category new error of Redundant alt attribute.